# XCode cannot create IPA

Tags: xcode, submit

My application compiles OK, and verifies.

But each of the Organizer options **Validate...**, **Share...**, **Submit...** just fail silently.

I'm using XCode version 3.2.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the Console application had some information:

> ```
> 30/12/10 13:51:27    Xcode[8458] Running /usr/bin/xcrun with (
>     "-sdk",
>     iphoneos,
>     PackageApplication,
>     "-v",
>     "/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Archived Applications/C201D5C0-2AB4-494B-A560-806AE36EF9A7.apparchive/Xxxxxx.app",
>     "-o",
>     "/var/folders/52/528Jj01wGtKYzlqffjXrck+++TI/-Tmp-/0610AAC0-E549-4F07-9496-08EFD6DFCAC3-8458-0000F00C5DE14F9F/Xxxxxx.ipa",
>     "--sign",
>     "iPhone Distribution: Xxxxxx",
>     "--embed",
>     "/Users/xxxxxx/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/66403280-7962-4A73-92D1-8FF34F65866C.mobileprovision"
> )
> 30/12/10 13:51:27   [0x0-0x439439].com.apple.Xcode[8458]    sh: /Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild: No such file or directory
> 30/12/10 13:51:27   [0x0-0x439439].com.apple.Xcode[8458]    /Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild fails with 32512 - Unknown error: 32512
> ```

After searching around for a while, it appears that my install was missing the directory **/Developer/usr/bin/**.

In a Terminal shell, I linked the latest XCode version directory:

> ```
> ln -s /Developer/XCode_3.2.5/usr/ /Developer/usr
> ```

and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to package your IPA file through command line, so you can have full log in it. Here is a post I wrote, check it out. 
http://www.nanaimostudio.com/blog/2011/4/17/xcode-build-and-archive-sharing-problem-and-solution.html